# Calculating monthly average from daily average (grouped by month)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VennkKZ_p8oks7Oh0O5nM4Htl3K0jttY0Eu0uIsy0LU/edit?usp=sharing) with three columns: one for dates, one for daily income and one for daily change rates.

[image]

I want to have a sum of all the daily income grouped by month as seen above. For that, on cell E2 I have the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula({unique(text(A2:A,"MMMYY")),
 sumif(text(A2:A,"MMMYY"),unique(text(A2:A,"MMMYY")),B2:B)})
```

It works well. Now, I would like to calculate the monthly average from the daily average (grouped by month). This is what I tried:

```
=ArrayFormula({unique(text(A2:A,""MMMYY"")),
 sumif(text(A2:A,""MMMYY""),
 unique(text(A2:A,""MMMYY"")),B2:B), AVERAGEif(text(A2:A,""MMMYY""),
 unique(text(A2:A,""MMMYY"")),C2:C)})
```

It doesn't work, it gives out the following:

```
ErrorFunction ARRAY_ROW parameter 3 has mismatched row size. Expected: 4. Actual: 1.
```

Edit: In the end, I found a way to make it work using query:

```
=query({ArrayFormula(EOMONTH(A2:A82,0
)),B2:B82,C2:C82},"Select Col1, Sum(Col2),avg(Col2) group by Col1 format Col1'MMM-YY'")
```

Any ideas how to solve this without query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following

```
=ArrayFormula({unique(text(A2:A,"MMMYY")),
 sumif(text(A2:A,"MMMYY"),unique(text(A2:A,"MMMYY")),B2:B), 
 sumif(text(A2:A,"MMMYY"),unique(text(A2:A,"MMMYY")),B2:B)/ 
 COUNTIF(text(A2:A,"MMMYY"),unique(text(A2:A,"MMMYY")))})
```

What we actually do is `sum/count=average`